# VB.Net Need to check if a string contains only one word but can contain punctuation

Tags: regex, vb.net, words

I need to check that my users insert only 1 word in a textbox.
This word can contain punctuation marks. Here are some examples of what can and cannot be inserted:

Cannot be inserted (multiple words):

- "hello there"

Can be inserted (single word, end of sentence, start of sentence):

- "word"
- "end."
- ". Start"
- "!! It"
- "end!!"

I am struggling with what checks I need to do. I already have:
`Regex.Matches(word, "\S+")`
which checks how many words are inserted. But how can I check if there is punctuation? Because ". Start" returns 2 words but this is valid.

Thanks

Comment: Would characters separated by punctuation (albeit odd) be valid or invalid?  eg: "abc!xyz" - is that one or two words?  EG are you looking for a situation where blocks of characters that have at least one space between them makes it invalid, everything else is valid?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `\p{L}` class to allow letters, and `\p{P}` to allow punctuation, and use anchors to mark start and end of the string. Optional groups will make sure we capture punctuation on both ends:

```
^(?:\p{P}+\s*)*[\p{P}\p{L}]+(?:\s*\p{P}+)*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vX0zX5/1) and [another demo on regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F%3A%5Cp%7BP%7D%2B%5Cs*)*%5B%5Cp%7BP%7D%5Cp%7BL%7D%5D%2B(%3F%3A%5Cs*%5Cp%7BP%7D%2B)*%5Cr%3F%24&i=hello%20there%0D%0A%0D%0ACan%20be%20inserted%3A%0D%0Aword%0D%0Aend.%0D%0A.%20Start%0D%0A!!%20It%0D%0Aend!!&o=m) (where I had to add `\r?` to show all matches with multiline flag on that site).

To exclude cases where words have punctuation inside (e.g. `new!word`), use

```
^(?:\p{P}+\s*)*\p{L}+(?:\s*\p{P}+)*$
```

*BUT* this will disallow hyphenated words.

See [demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/vX0zX5/2)

Comment: Does it work for you? Do you need any more assistance with the issue you are having?

Answer (score 1):

```
^((\W*\w+)|(\w+\W*))$
```

`^` start 
`\W*` to allow only non-word characters from 0 to infinite times
`\w+` to allow only word characters from 1 to infinite times
`|` to alternate
`$` end